# CrossTable and Ranges

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping

Can someone use the `CrossTable` function and still apply a range to the same crosstable output.

I am trying to CrossTable the following: annual income and a grade that is given to someone based on their credit score. Annual income happens to range from 0 to 9 million and crosstabling all these, I won't be able to view everything is there a way I can give the annual income a range?

```
CrossTable(loandata$annual_inc, 
           loandata$grade, 
           prop.r = TRUE, 
           prop.c = FALSE, 
           prop.t = FALSE, 
           prop.chisq = FALSE, 
           annual_inc = sample(1:421095, 500000))
```

Comment: `CrossTable` requires two categorical variables, so if you're giving it `annual_inc`, that will definitely cause a problem. If you're trying to bin the incomes into groups, do this first using `dplyr` - and make sure it's a categorical variable with a small/manageable number of categories - before calling `CrossTable`. Alternatively use `tally` in `dplyr` to get your contingency table.

Comment: If you provide a small sample of the data (<100 rows) I can post how to do this both ways.

Comment: Thanks @mysteRious, I was able to categorize the income to different levels and got a smaller table to work with now.

Comment: https://resources.lendingclub.com/LoanStats_2017Q4.csv.zip am working with this dataset